# Using UITableViewDataSource with Custom Cells Having Subviews

Tags: ios, uitableview, uikit

When using a custom cell in a UITableView I am getting a strange table overlap:

**Problem**

- scroll down & last  two rows have top  two rows painted over them!
- scroll up   & first two rows have bott two rows painted over them!

Here is the code for the UITableViewDataSource:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell : UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell!;

    let cellText:String = self.items[indexPath.row];

    let subjectField:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x:55, y: 25, width: 303, height:  25));
    
    subjectField.text = cellText;
    
    //cell.textLabel?.text = cellText;    //works fine!
    cell.addSubview(subjectField);        //fails  XX(!
    
    return cell;
}
```

Here is a screenshot:

- *Note*: '0  9' and '1  A' are the paint overs!
- *Ref*:  '0  9' is row#0 ('0   ') and row#9 ('   9')

[image]

**Question**

- Why does adding the subview cause the paint issue?
- What is the correct way to paint custom views into the cell?

**Context**

- My actual originating code uses custom cells in a custom tableview
- This code example here is a condensed version of the originating code. I can post whatever is needed to help resolve this!

Comment: I see two obvious issues with your code: 1) `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` might return null, so you need to create a new instance of cell. You'd better use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:`, which automatically allocates cell if needed, and 2) you're adding `subjectField` subview again and again when reusing a cell. You should either add it once in XIB or check if it is already added in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with cell identifier must be unique

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

```
    let  cellId:String = "Cell"+String(indexPath.row)
    var cell  = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellId)
    if (cell == nil){
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier:cellId)
    }
    let cellText:String = String(indexPath.row)
    let subjectField:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x:55, y: 25, width: 303, height:  25))

    subjectField.text = cellText

    (cell! as UITableViewCell).addSubview(subjectField)

    return cell! as UITableViewCell

}
```

Comment: I am taken aback, impressed and amazed - you fixed it!!!!!!!!!!! the (cell == nil) is key. Thank you for communicating the problem source here, AND THEN the solution!!!! Made my evening, thank you!!!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Dizzle
, Creating custom cell and using Control at run time as well as from Xib.

1) Create CustomCell in your ViewController either in Xib or Storyboard.

2) Give Identifier for your cell[image: Give Identifier for your cell]

3) In your **cellForRowAtIndexpath** data source method of tableview add below code

```
    static NSString *cellId = @"CustomIdenfier";
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:firstCellId];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellId];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        [self createCustomCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
    [self updateCustomCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
```

4) createCustomCell method If you add control in Xib then you don't need this method

```
-(void)createCustomCell:(CustomCell*)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath{
    //Here I am adding custom label run time, you can add
    // Any control in Xib and create a reference IBOutlet for it and user here.
    UILabel *lblTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, cell.contentView.frame.size.width-10, 30)];
    lblTitle.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    lblTitle.tag = 1;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:lblTitle];
}
```

5) updateCustomCell method

```
-(void)updateCustomCell:(CustomCell*)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath{

    UILabel *lblTitle = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
    [lblTitle setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",indexPath.row]];
}
```

//Edit 1
If not using Storyboard, then create custom extension of UITableviewCell.

```
//CustomCell.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell
@property (strong, nonatomic) UILabel *lblTitle;
@end


//CustomCell.m
#import "CustomCell.h"
@implementation CustomCell
@synthesize lblTitle;

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    NSLog(@"imgUrl:%@ txtName:%@",imgUser,txtName);
    // Initialization code
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(nullable NSString *)reuseIdentifier{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if(self){
        //Setup your Cell like initialising variables and setting frames of controls 
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
@end
```

Comment: I don't use Storyboards. I am 100% programmatic, sorry! Thank you for the detailed answer though!!!

Comment: J-Dizzle, Edited for using Custom Cell programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Rajesh Balam's Answer here is working form of my original code from my UITableViewDataSource!

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    /**********************************************************/
    /* @soln  a UNIQUE 'cellId' is the key                    */
    /**********************************************************/
    let  cellId  :String = "Cell" + String(indexPath.row);

    var cell : UITableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellId);

    if (cell == nil){
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier:cellId); //comment this out and watch it fail!
    }

    let cellText:String = self.items[indexPath.row];

    let subjectField:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x:55, y: 25, width: 303, height:  25));

    subjectField.text = cellText;

    (cell! as UITableViewCell).addSubview(subjectField);

    return cell! as UITableViewCell;

}
```

It works. THANK YOU Rajesh!!! :)