# UITableView in swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, parse-platform

can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code i always get the same data repeated in all cells

```
   override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel!.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
       let query = PFQuery(className:"book")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
          var contentString:String = String()
        if error == nil {
            print("Success retrieved \(objects!.count) scores.")
            if let objects = objects {
                for object in objects {
               let a:String = object.objectForKey("title") as! String
                contentString = a
            }
        }
              cell.textLabel!.text = contentString
    }}
    return cell
    }
```

Comment: This is similar to <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34524180/using-uitableviewdatasource-with-custom-cells-having-subviews/34524787?noredirect=1#comment56823623_34524787> Use tableview Cell id should be unique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be better to query all your data into viewDidLoad() or any life cycle you would like.

```
    var contentString = [String]() //<-- use an array of string instead of a string variable

 override func viewDidLoad()
   {
      super.viewDidLoad()
        let query = PFQuery(className:"book"){ query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

    if error == nil {
        print("Success retrieved \(objects!.count) scores.")
        if let objects = objects {
            for object in objects 
        {
            let value = object["title"] as! String
            self.contentString.append(value) //<-- save the query value to your array 
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData() //<--- then you reload your UI
      }
   }}
}

 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
   cell.textLabel!.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
   cell.textLabel!.text = self.contentString[indexPath.row] //<-- then assign the value into your cell 
   return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

content inside your loop should be like this.

```
let a:String = object.objectForKey("title") as! String
contentString += a
```

and i noticed your block calls for same query always. can you tell me whats the different there

```
 query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
      var contentString:String = String()
    if error == nil {
        print("Success retrieved \(objects!.count) scores.")
        if let objects = objects {
            for object in objects {
           let a:String = object.objectForKey("title") as! String
            contentString = a
        }
    }
          cell.textLabel!.text = contentString
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The query in `cellForRowAtIndex` is trouble.  Imagine, every time a cell comes into view, the code asks for every book from the server.

Put the query outside the datasource method (`viewWillAppear`, for example).  When the query is complete, initialize an array property with the results (e.g. `self.bookObjects = objects`).

Then in `cellForRowAtIndex`...

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
cell.textLabel!.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

// this is the important idea...
let object = self.bookObjects[indexPath.row]

let a:String = object.objectForKey("title") as! String
cell.textLabel!.text = a
return cell
```